# Is there a extension to help visually grouping tabs in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When working with multiple tabs open, it is important to be able to identify which tabs "go together" or are more important than others. Is there a extension to VS code that let you assign different color for each tab individually or somehow otherwise group tabs together without wasting screen estate using split views

Answer (score 2):

As of today it looks like there are no extensions allowing this. VSCode's team intentionally [doesn't want extensions to change the VScode UI](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/overview#no-dom-access), so it looks like it won't be possible with an extension anytime soon.

It is a feature I would very much like to see in VSCode too, there is a feature request on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/38889). Vote to get it seen and maybe added to VSCode !

Comment: I found one extension that allows you to somewhat group files together (useful when you have 20+ files open) : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jiapeiyao.tab-group it's not perfect but it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For now, that is not possible, probably in the future but not now. In my case I don't like to use splits so I just use groups with maximize group, so I can switch between projects tabs. Using `Ctrl + numb` is gonna send u to the groups tabs that u want:

```json
{
      "command": "runCommands",
      "key": "ctrl+1",
      "args": {
         "commands": [
            "workbench.action.focusFirstEditorGroup",
            "workbench.action.toggleMaximizeEditorGroup"
         ]
      }
   }
```

Same with `ctrl + 2,3,4` etc. You can add more options for just focus in groups if u split them or even move a tab no another group:

```json
{
      "command": "runCommands",
      "key": "ctrl+shift+o",
      "args": {
         "commands": [
            "workbench.action.moveEditorToNextGroup",
            "workbench.action.toggleMaximizeEditorGroup"
         ]
      }
   }
```

That's my approach, hope it helps